# how to disable or put an if conditions for required field in infoPath

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, infopath

I have two sections in infoPath form. I hide the required field of the first section, but I'm not able to submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to set the field as not required, but instead validate on form submit to see if the conditions are met and if not, make sure the field is not empty.

See this post for more details on how to proceed:
[How to create a validation rule](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/aaae4872-4527-4a5a-b700-a8c8a1835e30/infopath-2013-use-rules-to-display-validation-error?forum=sharepointcustomization)

Comment: Thanks for prompt respond. How can I put the if condition to submit the rest of the fields. I'm Ok to be able to hide the required field , but still getting error to submit. need help please . Thanks again

Comment: Are you hidding only in certain conditions?

Comment: no, If user select  "New" it should open the required field . If they select  "Current", no required field

Comment: But, by any means , they are able to submit both way

Comment: @Sai Can you edit your question and add an image of the form when it's a new and when it's a current user?

Comment: Did you look at douvillema?

Comment: @Sai, As I said earlier, can you post an image of the InfoPath form?

Comment: I did . Just refresh it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65308/discussion-between-douvillema-and-sai).